# Ajax call to controller to change session without pagereload

Tags: jquery, session, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

The application I'm building is a Webapplication that gives the user the possibility to enter new contracts for the upcoming weeks. We use a webservice which returns a JSON file to my ASP.net. Because of the complexity of the component we are trying to build, we pass the JSON to jquery to build the layout. In ASP.net / MVC 4, we are planning to store a session with the JSON file. When the user is editing or adding new values we check if the value has changed (in Jquery).

If this value is changed we would like to make a call to ASP to update the session with the JSON. How should we approach this? In our controller make an action like: Example/updateSession? In Ajax I guess this will be a POST method (Right?). But with I post I'm afraid I will have to do a page refresh and I really do not want this.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

### Edit - Example

currently I'm on the action: {controller}/{action} --> contracts/index, what will the ajaxcall be then? Post to contracts/updateJson? What will the return value be of that actionmethod (content / view / ... ) ?

Comment: Have you made any attempt at this?  An AJAX POST with jQuery (`$.post()`) doesn't refresh the page.  (AJAX in general, by design, doesn't refresh the page.)  You can simply post any value(s) you like from the client to a server resource and respond to those values in the action method (updating the session, in your case).  Then return from the action method a `Json()` result containing any information the client needs to update the UI.

Comment: Before I start I want to make sure that what I'm trying will have the good result. For example: currently I'm on the action: {controller}/{action} --> contracts/index, what will the ajaxcall be then? Post to contracts/updateJson? What will the return value be of that actionmethod? Thanks for answering

Comment: You'd want to create a separate action method for the AJAX call (probably on the same controller).  It works just like any other action method (you can restrict it to `HttpPost` as a method attribute if you'd like), and returns an `ActionResult` in the form of JSON data (by calling `Json()` instead of `View()` and passing a model to `Json()` to serialize into JSON data).  The actual return value would be whatever information the client needs after making the AJAX call.  If the client doesn't need anything other than a success indicator, `Json(true)` can work for that.

Comment: That sounds like what I need. I will get started on this tomorrow and I will let you know if that's what I need. Thanks again for responding